# How to find the correct expression for the gravitational field on a mass $m$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, symmetry

The condition is that the mass $m$ is placed between two concentric shells of masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ at some radius $r$.
Should the mass $M_1$ be considered as the mass $m$ is present at $r_1<r<r_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown that for a test mass $m$ **inside** a shell of mass $M$,
the net gravitational force from $M$ on $m$ is equal to zero.

Therefore in your example the mass $M_2$ is irrelevant. Now since $m$ is **outside** of $M_1$, the gravitational force from $M_1$ on $m$ is not zero.
In fact the gravitational force of $M_1$ on $m$ is the same as if we considered the whole shell $M_1$ to be concentrated in a point (namely the center of the mass shell).

See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem)